# Angular - Binding form data to form (form uses dev extreme form template)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, devexpress, devextreme

I am not clear how to bind any empty object so that the angular component can 
bind it to its scope.

My Plunker code is here : https://plnkr.co/edit/TvHVch?p=preview

In the above link, I have a master detail table and the details section has a tabbed view. Within the Bank Tab, I have a 'New Bank' button, on clicking this I launch a Form to capture new bank detials.

The problem I am facing is how do I instantiate an empty form? I tried the below but it is still causing issues. I am using devextreme angular forms (dx-form component), but the issue seems more on how to bind a java script object formData object.

```
  bindingOptions: {
                formData: {}
            },
```

In the plunker please refer bank.create.controller.js file for the complete code

Also I would like to manage it in such a way that I can show details if they are present (I want to use it as New and Edit form depending on presence of data)

Appreciate if you can help here.

```
function CreateBankController() {
     var vm = this;
        vm.popupForm = {
            colCount: 1,
            bindingOptions: {
                formData: {}
            },
            items: [{
                dataField: "fullName",
                validationRules: [{
                    type: "required",
                    message: "Full Name is required"
                }]
            }, {
                dataField: "shortName",
                validationRules: [{
                    type: "required",
                    message: "Short Name is required"
                }]
            }]
        };
```

ERROR

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullname' of undefined
    at t._updateFieldValue (http://localhost:8199/ui/vendor/devextreme/js/dx.all.js:34:18126)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8199/ui/vendor/devextreme/js/dx.all.js:34:17945)
    at Function.each (http://localhost:8199/ui/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js:365:19)
    at t._syncDataWithItems (http://localhost:8199/ui/vendor/devextreme/js/dx.all.js:34:17818)
    at t._init (http://localhost:8199/ui/vendor/devextreme/js/dx.all.js:34:17672)
    at t._init (http://localhost:8199/ui/vendor/devextreme/js/dx.all.js:10:1985)
    at t.endUpdate (http://localhost:8199/ui/vendor/devextreme/js/dx.all.js:11:2521)
    at t.endUpdate (http://localhost:8199/ui/vendor/devextreme/js/dx.all.js:10:29014)
    at t.endUpdate (http://localhost:8199/ui/vendor/devextreme/js/dx.all.js:10:1985)
    at t.endUpdate (http://localhost:8199/ui/vendor/devextreme/js/dx.all.js:14:19793) <div id="form" dx-form="formCtrl.formOptions" class="dx-widget" role="form">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `bindingOptions` to bind a widget option in two-way binding, this means that a value you assign to an option is a field in your scope. But, you are assigning a new object to the formData option, not a scope variable name. If you manually create a new object, don't use `bindingOptions`.

`vm.popupForm = {
    colCount: 1,
    formData: {},
    items: [{
        dataField: "fullName",
        validationRules: [{
            type: "required",
            message: "Full Name is required"
        }]
    }, {
        dataField: "shortName",
        validationRules: [{
            type: "required",
            message: "Short Name is required"
        }]
    }]
};`

See https://plnkr.co/edit/fdXBWPWUSJz9nMa5I4PL?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gosha. If I want to use the same for for a New object creation and also an Edit (update of the object), then how can I handle the binding in such scenarios. Should I create a vm.data (can be an empty {} or have date retrieved from my service) that is bound to the scope and then assigned to formDate within the bindingOptions

Answer (score 0):

Please use following approach, as your way for defining the formData is wrong. In V 16.2 this approach is allowed. So your function will be as:

```
function CreateBankController() {
 var vm = this;
    vm.option = {
        colCount: 1,
        formData:{},
        items: [{
            dataField: "fullName",
            validationRules: [{
                type: "required",
                message: "Full Name is required"
            }]
        }, {
            dataField: "shortName",
            validationRules: [{
                type: "required",
                message: "Short Name is required"
            }]
        }]
    };
```

For more info please visit [Devexpress Doc](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Form/Overview/jQuery/Light/) .